# svn file uploaded but doesn't open

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have added few files from my local system to server using tortoise svn. When I open svn link directly in my browser then it list my files which I have added from my local system. these are html files. When I open these files from svn then it shows me file contents in browser very well. but when I try to open these html file in browser using normal url then browser says file not found. My links which I am trying to open are as follows:

SVN URL:
http://www.mysite.com/trunk/site/index.html (Works fine)
Normal URL:
http://www.mysite.com/index.html (File Not Found)

I have other files in svn repository at same location where index.hmtl is like index2.html it works fine with both urls svn and normal url.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need more info on your setup - like how the repo is linked to something that is served at your site?

Comment: @qwera - ok, that is not going  to help any bit.

Comment: And how does your site contents gets updated from the SVN trunk? How is the repository linked to your site?

Comment: I have added these files using Tortoise SVN. First of all I've added these files then checkout. When I open trunk with browser then it shows me file but when I browser these file with normal url then Browser sends an error "File Not Found"

Comment: Why do would you expect this "normal url" to work at all. If you commit files on the trunk they will be under trunk path. That's just how SVN works.

Answer (score 1):

Well, svn does not expose magically your files into a web site.

First URL is managed by your web server using webdav.

Second link is actual production and has to be managed as a web server. Most probably, your apache configuration is faulty.

Svn being exported as web is just a mean of exposing it (just like ssh or filesystem), it's not supposed to be used as production exposure for a website.

Moreover, you will want to

- define a strategy to update your "production server" from your repository (i.e. when do you want to have your latest files up to date) : depending on your strategy, can be done periodically (cron), on certain actions (hook in svn)
- don't forget to block in .htaccess or your apache configuration access to .svn folder

Hope this helps,